# Russian mom traveling from US to Russian Federation with little kid

Tags: visas, usa, air-travel, children, russian-citizens

Good day,

I´m Russian and I live in Ecuador, South America. I´ll be traveling from US to Russian Federation with my Ecuadorian 3 years old kid, but without my husband, please What documents I need to travel without problems?

Thanks

Comment: Are you flying directly to Russia from the US, or do you have a layover in any other country?

Comment: On top of whatever visas you might need for transit, you should expect questioning on why the child is traveling with only one parent. The US CBP recommends a notarized letter signed by both parents granting permission for the trip. If the child's father is not involved in custody, you should have documents (e.g., divorce and custody decree) explaining the situation.

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify. Putting on hold.